# Combine and Sum the data with the same date

Tags: laravel, collections

Forgive me for my bad english because it's not my first language
I have a blockers on how to combine and add some of the data
I have this data from my first collection

**first Collection**

```
[
   {
      "dateTime": "10/01/2022",
      "gc": 0,
      "credit": 20,
      "debit": 1000,
      "voucher": 0,
      "e_gift": 0,
      "cash": 3000
    }, 
    {
      "dateTime": "10/02/2022",
        "gc": 0,
        "credit": 10,
        "debit": 10,
        "voucher": 0,
        "e_gift": 0,
        "cash": 100
    },
]
```

**2nd Collection**

```
 [
    {
         "dateTime": "10/01/2022",
         "Gross Total": 6000,
         "Discount": 300
      },
      {
           "dateTime": "10/02/2022",
           "Gross Total": 4000,
           "Discount": 100
       },
    ]
```

What result i want is they will combine based on date and all the data from first collection will be add to gross total
result is like this

```
[
    {
      "dateTime": "10/01/2022",
        "gc": 0,
        "credit": 20,
        "debit": 1000,
        "voucher": 0,
        "e_gift": 0,
        "cash": 3000
        "Gross Total": 6000,
        "Discount": 300
        "total amount" : 10020  

    },
{
       "dateTime": "10/02/2022",
        "gc": 0,
        "credit": 10,
        "debit": 10,
        "voucher": 0,
        "e_gift": 0,
        "cash": 100
        "Gross Total": 4000,
        "Discount": 100,
        "total amount" : 4120

    }, 
]
```

Comment: Ok, now that we know what you _want_ can you please show what you already _have_? Please post your code in your question along with any error you might get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's call them `collection1` and `collection2`, using Collection methods such as `merge` and `push` this should work:

```
$merged = collect();
            foreach(collection1 as $e){
                $temp = collect($e)->merge($collect2->where('dateTime', $e['dateTime'])->first());
                $merged->push($temp);
            }
            return $merged;
```

Notice that i've created these variables using a sample from your code above:

```
 $collect2 = collect([
            [
                 "dateTime"=> "10/01/2022",
                 "Gross Total"=> 6000,
                 "Discount"=> 300
                ],
             [
                   "dateTime"=> "10/02/2022",
                   "Gross Total"=> 4000,
                   "Discount"=> 100
                ],
        ]);
```

please check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) for more details

Comment: kinda stuck in this problem thanks alot .. just to clarfiy im having an error with **$e['dateTime']** it should be **$e->dateTime** . Thank you so much for giving me such a wonderful idea

Comment: i guessed that, that's why i put a note down, cuz i collected arrays, and you are getting objects from your query